# How to save output from bash script to image file with convert imagemagick

Tags: bash, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Hi gus i'm just trying to save my output script to image file with convert imagemagick , but i have an issue with the result did any clue for fixing my issue ? the image file isnt generate in the right way ,
here my script result [is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzUaV.jpg)

and i run a command

```
./script.sh | convert label:@- myscript.png
```

and the result image isnt show with correct

Comment: In what respect is the generated image not correct? The picture you linked at, looks like a good screenshot.

Comment: that was the result when i run script without use convert , and if i use convert for generate image from script , the result isnt like the screenshoot i was take

Comment: So your script.sh is writing a jpeg file to stdout, and you posted just this jpg file. But you still didn't show the incorrect png image generated, so I have no clue what went wrong. At least you need to describe what is wrong with the png, and since having a pipe is is not relevant to the problem, I would separate the issues: Do a `script.sh >myscript.jpg` and then focus on `convert label:@- myscript.png <myscript.jpg`. The latter statement is equivalent to your original one and easier to discuss.

Comment: @user1934428 here is the image result https://imgur.com/0QoJDUU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do that in ImageMagick would be:

```
convert label:@scriptfile.sh script.png
```

But you may have to edit your ImageMagick policy.xml file to enable the use of @.